# ASP.NET Active Directory Authentication on one form

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory

Environment: IIS7.5, .net 4.5
I want anonymous access to all of the pages except one. This one page must only be visible for users in my domain. This page should also automatically use users current windows domain account without asking him to enter it.
If I use this setting in web.config/IIS:

authentication mode="Windows"

It asks for credentials for every page I try to open and when I enter my domain account I can see the page. So there are two problems with this. It did not restrict it just for one page and it did not use my windows account automatically.
Is there any out of the box solution for this. Perhaps to allow anonymous access in ISS and use some attribute on the class to say it needs authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow anonymous access in IIS for the application folder, and set the authentication method to Integrated Windows authentication for just the page that you want to restrict.

[How to configure Authentication in IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324274)

What browser type is prompting for credentials? In my experience Internet Explorer will automatically use windows accounts, but Firefox requires that I edit about:config:

1. Open Firefox
2. In the address bar type: about:config
3. Firefox3.x and later requires you to agree that you will proceed with caution.
4. Modify network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris by double clicking the row and enter the host name(s) of your server.

Comment: The link you have provided describes the process on windows server 2003 and IIS6. IIS7 does not have those options mentioned in step 3 and 4 to specify authentication per page... And about the credentials prompt, it asks me for them in Chrome. Could it be because I entered a site name/domain that is not in my internal network?

Comment: To specify authentication per page in IIS7, first select the page's folder in the tree on the left side. Note that the path to the folder is displayed at the top. Then on the right side at the bottom click "Content View". Right click the file you want to configure to display its context menu, 
and choose "Switch to Features View". Now the path displayed at the top should include the file name. Double click Authentication and enable Anonymous.

Comment: According to http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-to-disable-the-browser-login-prompt-when-using-windows-authentication-
Chrome takes its trusted sites settings from the same Internet Options as Internet Explorer. You can access the dialog from Chrome here:

Properties -> Show advanced settings -> Change proxy settings -> Security -> Trusted sites

Please note: you will be asked to log in the first time you access the trusted site.

Comment: One test you can try to see whether the issue is that the site name/domain is not in your internal network is to try accessing it with Internet Explorer. If that works without prompting for credentials, then I would infer that the Chrome setting is the issue.

Comment: Following your steps to specify authentication per page worked. It was very helpful where you stated that the name of the part I am configuring is shown on top of the window. And also adding the site to allowed list in IE options in steps you described enabled the single sign on, so no prompts anymore. Thank you.